# Django Rest Framework PUT view saying validated_data is unfilled

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to use Django Rest Framework for updating my database using the HTTP PUT, but when on my client I get the error `Exception Value: update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'validated_data'` and in the python code I get an error that says `Validated_data unfilled`.

Here is my model code:

```
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    calle_numero = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    zona_residencial = models.ForeignKey(Zona, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    numero_habitantes = models.IntegerField()
    tipo_residente = models.CharField(max_length=100,
                               choices=[(tag.value, tag.value) for tag in TipoHabitanteEnum])
    codigo_acceso = models.CharField(max_length=6, default="000000")
    status_activacion = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Residente'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Residentes'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre
```

here is my serializer code:

```
    class Meta:
        model = Residente
        fields = '__all__'
```

And my view (PUT method where the error is) code:

```
        """
        Modifica un residente
        """
        try:
            id_residente = self.queryset.get(pk=kwargs["pk"])
            serializer = ResidenteSerializer
            update_residente = serializer.update(id_residente, request.data)
            return Response(ResidenteSerializer(update_residente).data)
        except Residente.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(
                data={
                    "message": "El residente con id {} no existe".format(kwargs["pk"])
                },
                status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND
            )
```

in the `update_residente = serializer.update(id_residente, request.data)` is the validated_data error is and that's why I can't update my database but I don't know how to fix it.

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating the serializer object.

change the code to this:

```
"""
Modifica un residente
"""
try:
    id_residente = self.queryset.get(pk=kwargs["pk"])
    serializer = ResidenteSerializer(id_residente, data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=False):
        update_residente = serializer.save()
        return Response(ResidenteSerializer(update_residente).data)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=400)
except Residente.DoesNotExist:
    return Response(
            data={
               "message": "El residente con id {} no existe".format(kwargs["pk"])
                },
                status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND
            )
```

Suggestion for simpler code:

```
id_residente = get_object_or_404(self.queryset, pk=kwargs["pk"])
serializer = ResidenteSerializer(id_residente, data=request.data)
if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save()
return Response(serializer.data)
```

This code is same as the above but simpler.

use `from rest_framework.generics import get_object_or_404` to import the function.